Include errors with IntelliSenseMode: changes from "macos-gcc-x86" to "macos-clang-x86" when compilerPath: "/usr/bin/g++"
I am currently using Visual Studio Code on macOS Ventura 13.6.5. I have created a C/C++ project and set up G++ as my compiler. I have defined my build settings using Makefiles and everything is working fine, which means that my project now compiles correctly.
However, I'm having trouble configuring the Intellisense tool to assist me with code completion, error detection, and other features. Specifically, I'm encountering include errors for C++ standard headers like <string> and <vector> as shown in the attached image.

Below are the contents of my c_cpp_properties.json file:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/tr1",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin22/13/include/ssp",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin22/13/include-fixed",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/Solution"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

As you can see on my c_cpp_properties.json, I have tried defining the compilerPath variable to point to the compiler that I am using which in this case is g++. I have confirmed that the path to the compiler is correct.
I also tried to make sure that I included the gcc headers into the includePath. To find where my gcc headers were located, I executed the following command:
gabriel@pandora ssp % sudo find /usr -name stdio.h 
Password:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin22/13/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin22/13/include-fixed/stdio.h


However, for some reason, IntelliSense refuses to take my settings from c_cpp_properties.json and instead, tries to get back into using clang settings. At least that is my understanding after restarting Visual Studio and looking at the following messages on the output panel:

Does anyone here knows how to fix this issue? Any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Edit:
I was able to fix the problem with the headers using the link provided here. However, that caused another problem with subsequent build errors of code that is valid. I suspect that Intellisense is either trying to check for C code while my program is written in C++ or something else that I have no idea is completely wrong.
I would appreciate any hints or possible solutions to this.
Thanks,


See here how to get GCC default search paths.

Thank you for the link. It was very helpful to solve the header problems although I am still getting some other build errors. Please refer to the edit section.

I'll wager /usr/bin/g++ is pointing to Apple Clang (run /usr/bin/g++ --version), and your homebrew-installed GCC is somewhere in /opt/ or /usr/local/cellar or something. In other words, if you want your homebrew GCC, actually point to it instead of Apple Clang. So in large part I suspect this is duplicating Mac clang installation seems to override GCC install.
As for the VS Code-specific aspect of the question, if you correctly specify compilerPath in c_cpp_properties.json, you shouldn't also need to specify the toolchain's system headers in includePath- cpptools should be able to query for them (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference).

You are completely right. /usr/bin/g++ is not pointing to GCC instead is pointing to Apple clang version 14.0.3. Thanks for your answer.
